# Why does Visual Studio switch focus to another pane after Quick Actions?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Here's the scenario: I'm coding along, and I reference a type that I haven't imported with a `using` statement yet.

Since I don't want to slow down and grab the mouse, I just do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> to bring up Quick Actions, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept the top suggestion of adding the correct `using` statement.

About half the time, all is well! But I get some weird behavior the other 50% of the time:

- Sometimes, the focus switches to some other visible pane (Output, Solution Explorer, Properties...)
- Sometimes, the focus stays in the Code pane "sort of". I can't type, but using the arrow keys works to move around the little shaded row that indicates your current line

This isn't unique to this particular Quick Action, it's just the one that bites me most often. Executing any Quick Action suggestion via the keyboard potentially triggers this. **However**, I've never seen it happen when I use the mouse to click on the suggestion I want to execute.

What's going on here?

Comment: If anyone happens to find this via Google, the easy "fix" is to press F7 to switch back to the Code pane. I'm still not sure why it happens, though.

Comment: Esc also works, may be faster than pressing F7 for some

Comment: @Domysee: Sadly, pressing Esc didn't work for me.

Comment: Interesting, maybe its a little different on my machine because I'm running German Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug appears to be fixed in [Visual Studio 2015 Update 1](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx). After installing, I no longer have to press <kbd>F7</kbd> to switch back to the Code pane.